# Using Fragment with tabs .. The specified child already has a parent

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm building an app like WhatsApp using 3 tabs and every tab have a `Fragment`. In my first `Fragment` I have a `RecyclerView`.

Win a set the SectionsPagerAdapter to start width the RecyclerView Fragment 
like this:

```
inner class SectionsPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {

        override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            //return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1)
            when(position){
                0 ->  return Fragmenttask.newInstance()
                1 ->  return FragmentChat.newInstance()
                2 ->  return FragmentMaps.newInstance()
                else  -> {
                    return null!!
                }
            }
        }

        override fun getCount(): Int {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3
        }
    }
```

It give me this error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                             Process: com.deraah.mohamed.deraahpro, PID: 21993
>                                                                             java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a
>   parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4937)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4768)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addView(ViewPager.java:1477)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4708)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4681)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1425)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1740)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:794)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2580)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2367)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2322)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2199)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:651)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:145)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1236)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:662)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:624)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:605)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener.onTabSelected(TabLayout.java:2170)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.dispatchTabSelected(TabLayout.java:1165)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1158)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1128)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab.select(TabLayout.java:1427)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.performClick(TabLayout.java:1537)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

**UPDATE**

My fragments:

FragmentChat:

```
/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * [FragmentChat.OnFragmentInteractionListener] interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the [FragmentChat.newInstance] factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
class FragmentChat : Fragment() {

    private var mListener: OnFragmentInteractionListener? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_chat, container, false)
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    fun onButtonPressed(uri: Uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener!!.onFragmentInteraction(uri)
        }
    }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
        super.onAttach(context)
    }

    override fun onDetach() {
        super.onDetach()
        mListener = null
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     *
     *
     * See the Android Training lesson [Communicating with Other Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) for more information.
     */
    interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        fun onFragmentInteraction(uri: Uri)
    }

    companion object {

        // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
        fun newInstance(): FragmentChat {
            val fragment = FragmentChat()
            val args = Bundle()
            fragment.arguments = args
            return fragment
        }
    }
}// Required empty public constructor
```

FragmentMaps:

```
/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * [FragmentMaps.OnFragmentInteractionListener] interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the [FragmentMaps.newInstance] factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
class FragmentMaps : Fragment() {

    private var mListener: OnFragmentInteractionListener? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_maps, container, false)
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    fun onButtonPressed(uri: Uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener!!.onFragmentInteraction(uri)
        }
    }

    override fun onDetach() {
        super.onDetach()
        mListener = null
    }


    interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        fun onFragmentInteraction(uri: Uri)
    }

    companion object {
        // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
        fun newInstance(): FragmentMaps {
            val fragment = FragmentMaps()
            val args = Bundle()
            fragment.arguments = args
            return fragment
        }
    }
}// Required empty public constructor
```

Fragmenttask :

```
class Fragmenttask : Fragment() {

    private var mListener: OnFragmentInteractionListener? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val CustumViewtask = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragmenttask, container, false)
        val taskMainRV = CustumViewtask.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_main) as RecyclerView
        //taskMainRV.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)

        taskMainRV.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        //recyclerView_main.adapter = MainAdapter()

        fetchJson(taskMainRV)

        return taskMainRV
    }

    fun fetchJson(RSV: RecyclerView) {

        //SharedPreferences
        val MY_APP_INFO: String = "UserInfo"
        val prefs = activity.getSharedPreferences(MY_APP_INFO, AppCompatActivity.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val LoggedUserId = prefs.getString("UserId", null)
        println("your code is : $LoggedUserId")

        println("Attempting to Fetch JSON")

        val url = "http://Restful.com/get_tasks.php"

        val client = OkHttpClient()

        val formBody = FormBody.Builder().add("UserId", LoggedUserId).build()

        val request = Request.Builder().url(url)
                .post(formBody)
                .build()

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response?) {
                val body = response?.body()?.string()
                println("mohamed : $body")

                val gson = GsonBuilder().create()

                val tasksfeed = gson.fromJson(body, M_tasksFeed::class.java)

                activity.runOnUiThread {
                    RSV.adapter = MainAdaptertasks(tasksfeed)
                }

            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call?, e: IOException?) {
                println("Failed to execute request")
            }
        })
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    fun onButtonPressed(uri: Uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener!!.onFragmentInteraction(uri)
        }
    }

    override fun onDetach() {
        super.onDetach()
        mListener = null
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     *
     *
     * See the Android Training lesson [Communicating with Other Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) for more information.
     */
    interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        fun onFragmentInteraction(uri: Uri)
    }

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): Fragmenttask {
            val fragment = Fragmenttask()
            val args = Bundle()
            fragment.arguments = args
            return fragment
        }
    }
}// Required empty public constructor
```

Comment: the RecyclerView Fragment name is Fragmenttask

Comment: remove `else  -> {
                return null!!
            }` condition for test case

Comment: the same error java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView()

Comment: @unpitted.com https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28071349/the-specified-child-already-has-a-parent-you-must-call-removeview-on-the-chil

Answer (score 2):

You are returning  wrong `view` check in your **`Fragmenttask`** `Fragment`

**Use this**

```
 return CustumViewtask
```

**Instead of this**

```
return taskMainRV
```

Change your code like this

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val CustumViewtask = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragmenttask, container, false)
        val taskMainRV = CustumViewtask.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_main) as RecyclerView
        //taskMainRV.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)

        taskMainRV.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        //recyclerView_main.adapter = MainAdapter()

        fetchJson(taskMainRV)

        return CustumViewtask
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem coming from

```
       else  -> {
                return null!!
            }
```

Try this way

```
override fun getItem(position: Int): android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        //return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1)
       var fragment: android.support.v4.app.Fragment? = null
       when (position) {
           0 -> fragment = Fragmenttask.newInstance()
           1 -> fragment = FragmentChat.newInstance()
           2 -> fragment = FragmentMaps.newInstance()
       }

       return fragment!!
   }

   override fun getCount(): Int {
       return 3           //no of cases/fragments
   }

}
```

**`FYI`**

You must call [**`removeView()`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28071349/the-specified-child-already-has-a-parent-you-must-call-removeview-on-the-chil) .

Each Fragment section

```
 View viewOBJ = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_child, parent_layout, false);

  return viewOBJ ;
```

Comment: wen i click the last one FragmentMaps.newInstance() and i click to the first Fragmenttask.newInstance()  they give me the same error java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView()

Comment: @unpitted.com In your fragment class, you should return VIEW

Comment: @unpitted.com Kindly return proper view `Fragmenttask ` fragment section

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure while inflating fragment's view you have set the attachRootView to false?

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false)
```

Comment: val CustumViewtask = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragmenttask, container, false)
        val taskMainRV = CustumViewtask.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_main) as RecyclerView