# How to add & stack childView to a LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I got `The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.` ERROR.

But I do not want to remove the parent view.

If you click a button, a message must be added at the end of LinearLayout's childViews.

This is my Java code:

```
    Button addBTN = findViewById(R.id.addButton);
    LinearLayout messageListLL = findViewById(R.id.messageList_LinearLayout);
    addBTN.setOnClickListener((v) -> {
        MessageItem messageItem = new MessageItem();
        View messageView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.item_message, messageListLL);
        messageListLL.addView(messageView, messageListLL.getChildCount());
    });
```

This is the part of activity's xml:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/adView"
    android:layout_below="@id/userContainer"
    android:background="#CCC"
    android:padding="15dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/messageList_LinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/design_default_color_primary"
            android:text="ADD"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This is item_message.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="#FFD9D9" />
</LinearLayout>
```

So, I'd like to make a view with `item_message` and put it into `LinearLayout` in the activity's xml, which has `messageList_LinearLayout` for the id attribute.

The button is also in the LinearLayout. The button must be placed at the end of the LinearLayout.

And whenever, I click the button, a message view must be created and added at the end of the messageList and also before the button.

Comment: Have u check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/28071349/7666442

Comment: Try using `View message = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_message,null);`.

Comment: @Nilesh Rathod Yes, but I don't want to remove any views.

Comment: @ADM Thanks, problem solved. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just change the third parameter into `null`.

```java
View messageView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(this, R.layout.item_message, null);
messageListLL.addView(messageView, messageListLL.getChildCount() - 1)
```

The third parameter specifies its `root` view. You can inflate the messageView without any roots.

Comment: Could you tell me the problems with my code and what does `null` do?

Comment: null is for not to attach with parent but best way is to `LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate( R.layout.item_message, messageListLL, false);`

Comment: Please explain your answer with further details. Code only answers are not helpful for learners.