# "The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first" the second time I create an AlertDialog

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog, android-view, layout-inflater

When I click on the button for the first time, it runs normally. But when I click on it for the second time, the program crashes:
`The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.`

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val view1 = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_view1, null, false)

        val btn1 = view1.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn1)
        val btn2 = view1.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn2)
        val btn3 = view1.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn3)

        btn1.setOnClickListener {
            binding.textView.setTextColor(Color.RED)
        }
        btn2.setOnClickListener {
            binding.textView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE)
        }
        btn3.setOnClickListener {
            binding.textView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN)
        }

        binding.button.setOnClickListener {

            AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Color")
                .setView(view1)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("ok", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { _, _ ->
                })
                .create().show()
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28071349/the-specified-child-already-has-a-parent-you-must-call-removeview-on-the-chil)

Comment: That duplicate isn't quite right.  This is not the same problem, even if it's the same crash.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're creating and holding a reference to `view1` once:

```kotlin
    val view1 = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_view1, null, false)
```

but then trying to use that same view every time the button is clicked:

```kotlin
    binding.button.setOnClickListener {

        AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Color")
            .setView(view1)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("ok", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { _, _ ->
            })
            .create().show()
    }
```

To solve it, you should move your setup code inside the button click listener, so that you get a fresh `view1` for each new `AlertDialog`:

```kotlin
    binding.button.setOnClickListener {
        val view1 = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_view1, null, false)

        val btn1 = view1.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn1)
        val btn2 = view1.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn2)
        val btn3 = view1.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn3)

        btn1.setOnClickListener {
            binding.textView.setTextColor(Color.RED)
        }
        btn2.setOnClickListener {
            binding.textView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE)
        }
        btn3.setOnClickListener {
            binding.textView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN)
        }

        AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Color")
            .setView(view1)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("ok", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { _, _ ->
            })
            .create().show()
    }
```